# Add object key to end of a href url link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, href

Having an issue where I'm trying to add the key of my object at the end of a URL. It works as a button but for some reason the key isn't being displayed with the href? I usually would do + but with react it's a bit hard to understand what I'm doing wrong.. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

```
{
    Object.keys(listItems).map(function(key) {
      return (
        <a>
          <ListItemText button='true' href="https://something.com/user/"{...key} inset primary={listItems[key]}></ListItemText>
        </a>
      )
      })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood it completely, but here we go, maybe this will work:

```
Object.keys(listItems).map(function(key) {
      return (
        <a>
          <ListItemText button='true' href={"https://something.com/user/" + key} inset primary={listItems[key]}></ListItemText>
        </a>
      )
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(listItems).map(function(key) {
  return (
    <a>
      <ListItemText button='true' href={`https://something.com/user/${key}`} 
      inset primary={listItems[key]}></ListItemText>
    </a>
  )
 })
```

this. is another form of concatenation on javascript/typescript.

Comment: Hi Matheus, welcome to SO, it would be nice if you could add some description/explanation to your code (e.g. why it works/which ECMAScript introduced this)